# Connection string (webjobs) in test deployment slot

Tags: azure, connection-string, publish, azure-webjobs, azureportal

It seems I can't get any control over the connection string my webjob is using. There are probably more questions involved, but I don't know what exactly is causing my issues.

I have a production environment, and a test deployment slot. There are 3 webjobs running on both. All web jobs and my website have a connection string defined in their app.config resp. web.config.

```
    <add name="SQLAZURECONNSTR_MyConnectionStringName" connectionString="Server=xxx;Database=MyTestDatabase;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I do a swap, the used connection string is swapped as well, I've read that's as designed. Now, I want my test environment to always point to my test DB, so after the swap, I try to override my connection string in the azure portal, but that has no effect. Test environment is still using Production DB.

Only after I publish my local version (with conn. string pointing to TestDB) to staging, I see my test-website is pointing to testDB again (why is it not overridden by Azure Portal connection string setting?)

However, last night, I did a swap, set my connection strings (in app.config and web.config) to TestDB, publish to testEnvironment, also published webjobs to testEnvironment. They still worked with productionDB... I login to my azure portal -> Test deployment slot. It shows no web jobs (while I'm positive they are running).

Note: I have a lot of problems with publishing since I use webjobs. So there is a probability that something went wrong with publishing as well.

A lot of text, mostly to try to elaborate my confusion. It might boil down to a few questions:

- In what cases does the azure portal connection string setting override the connection strings in web/app.config?
- Why do my webjobs show inconsistent behavior in terms of conn. string?
- How can I get rid of this manual webjob publish nonsense once and for all, I'm using settings.job way to publish schedule webjobs, that solved a few, but not all of my problemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [blog post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/11/azure-websites-slots/) should answer your deployment slots questions.

In short:

- The portal connection strings always overrides the web app or webjob web.config/app.config connection strings.
- The portal can sometime show invalid data regarding webjobs (Azure portal bug), one credible way to see this data is by going to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/webjobs
- Just need to make sure the binaries are deployed to the right location (`d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\{job_type}\{job_name}.

Comment: Your blog post actually helped me a lot. What I did now is:
- Rename the connectionstring, I thought the prefix was necessary, but it occurred I was wrong about that.
- Set the sticky connection string using powershell.

I have one weird behavior that I still don't understand though. My web jobs are triggered twice every time they run. I used to use a scheduled trigger, now I'm using the settings.job with the onDemand trigger.

My azure portal shows only 1 web job occurence (though log shows it runs twice every time), the API url you mention also shows 1 occurence. Where is my hidden webjob?

Comment: That's odd. Would be best to start separate question to discuss this double-firing rather than trying to solve it over this question's comments.

Comment: Could you help me address this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790985/azure-webjob-triggered-twice