# Azure Webjob triggered twice

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I used to use a scheduled trigger when deploying my webjobs, due to some problems I decided to use the settings.job with the onDemand trigger.

My azure portal shows only 1 web job occurence, but in the log I can see it runs twice every time.

In my https://echtemaaltijd.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/webjobs page, I see one instance per webjob, when I look at the scheduler log urls, I also see it's triggered only once.

To prevent from triggering twice, I cleared the settings schedule property, and as a result its triggered only once. (That is the current situation in above url for two webjobs)

Somehow the "old" schedule webjob is still triggering, and I don't know why this happened and how I can delete these schedulers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to go disable/delete your old Azure Scheduler Job that is still running invoking your WebJob. You can find more details [in this blog](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html) on how to find that in the portal, and how Azure Scheduler / WebJobs interact in general. Once you stop the Azure Scheduler Job, you'll be able to use your settings.job schedule.

Comment: That's it, thanks! I never realized that this "scheduler" page with a webjob collection in manageAzure was a different thing than the webjobs view in the new Azure portal.

Comment: Also note that there is now a "Logic Apps" option in Azure in which you can trigger a webjob at a specific interval or time of day.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My job is running twice every 15 mins when it should just run once every 15 mins. One right after the other. I have been over this post and there is nothing in my scheduler at all. How the hell do I stop this happening?